VBA Userform ListBox - Run-Time Error 380. Could not set the List property. Invalid property value
I've been using "On Error Resume Next" for a while to 'step over' this error because I've been getting the correct results despite the error. However, now, I have a new issue to resolve, but I first need to fix the 380 error. I have notated the line that errors out and the On Error Resume Next is disabled.
Private Sub imgSearchlstMaster_Click() 'Search multiple orders button
    Dim sat    As Long
    Dim s      As Long
    Dim c      As Integer
    Dim deg1   As String
    Dim deg2   As String
    Dim RN     As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Setting to 'false' speeds up the macro
    txtShopOrdNum = ""                            'clear txtShopOrdNum, v13

    Sheets("Master").Activate
    If Me.txtSearch.Value = "" Then               'Condition if the textbox is blank
        MsgBox "Please enter a search value.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Search" 'vbOKOnly shows only the OK button, vbExclamation shows exclamation point icon
        txtSearch.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If cboSearchItem.Value = "" Then              ' Condition if combobox is blank
        MsgBox "Please select search criteria.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, ""
        cboSearchItem.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With lstMaster                                'Need to clear the listbox first
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = 125
        .ColumnWidths = "0;0;40;48;108;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;50;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;72;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;50;35;0;0;0;0;0;0;45;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;100;0;0;"
        'Must include the total ColumnCount and all ColumnWidths for the code to work. ColumnWidths = 0 do not appear in the listbox.
    End With
    
    Call Main                                     'Progress bar
    deg2 = txtSearch.Value
    
    Select Case cboSearchItem.Value
        Case "Shop Order"
            RN = 5  'E                          'column number
        Case "Suffix"
            RN = 4  'D
        Case "Proposal"
            RN = 14 'O
        Case "PO"
            RN = 23 'X
        Case "SO"
            RN = 33 'AH
        Case "Quote"
            RN = 34 'AI
        Case "Transfer Order"
            RN = 41 'AP
        Case "Customer Nickname"
            RN = 96 'CR
        Case "End User Nickname"
            RN = 121 'DQ
    End Select
    
    For sat = 4 To Cells(Rows.Count, RN).End(xlUp).Row '4 = first row of databody
        deg1 = Cells(sat, RN)
        If UCase(deg1) Like "*" & UCase(deg2) & "*" Then 'case insensitive AND searches the entire string
            lstMaster.AddItem
            For c = 0 To 125                     'column indices, total columns
            'On Error Resume Next 'added this to get past Run-Time error 308
                lstMaster.List(s, c) = Cells(sat, c + 1) 'Run-Time error 308. Could not set the List property. Invalid property value
                's = count of txtSearch.Value results
                'c = (total number of columns)
                'c + 1 = (total number of columns + 1)
                'sat = first blank row
                'deg1 = lower bound value in column RN (sorting will change this)
                'deg2 = txtSearch.Value
                'RN = column number of cboSearchItem.Value
            Next c
            s = s + 1                             'This MUST follow "Next c", this increments s for each new record added
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    lblTotalSearchResults = lstMaster.ListCount
    lblTotalOrders = Range("MASTER").Rows.Count
    
    'Debug.Print s, c, c + 1, sat, deg1, deg2, RN, lblTotalSearchResults, lblTotalOrders
    
End Sub  'imgSearchlstMaster_Click()




There are 125 columns in ListBox (.ColumnCount = 125). For c = 0 To 125 tries to load 126 items. That's the root cause of run-time error. You can change 125 to 124 to fix it.

However, a more efficient approach involves using an array to collect all matched items and then updating the List (or Column) property all at once. (Thanks for @T.M.'s comment)


    Dim RowCnt As Long, iR As Long, arrRes()
    RowCnt = Cells(Rows.Count, RN).End(xlUp).Row
    For sat = 4 To RowCnt '4 = first row of databody
        deg1 = Cells(sat, RN)
        If UCase(deg1) Like "*" & UCase(deg2) & "*" Then 'case insensitive AND searches the entire string
            ReDim Preserve arrRes(125, iR)
            lstMaster.AddItem
            For c = 0 To 124                     'column indices, total columns
                arrRes(c, iR) = Cells(sat, c + 1)
            Next c
            iR = iR + 1
            s = s + 1                             'This MUST follow "Next c", this increments s for each new record added
        End If
    Next
    lstMaster.Column = arrRes


btw, I would suggest loading only the 10 must-have columns into the ListBox to improve efficiency, considering that there are only 10 visible columns among the total 125 columns.

Option Explicit
Private Sub imgSearchlstMaster_Click() 'Search multiple orders button
    Dim sat    As Long
    Dim s      As Long
    Dim c      As Integer
    Dim deg1   As String
    Dim deg2   As String
    Dim RN     As Integer
     ' modify as needed
    Const COL_WIDE = "40;48;108;50;72;50;35;45;100;100"
    Const COL_INDEX = "3,4,5,14,23,33,34,41,96,121" ' Col index which is showed in ListBox
    Const START_ROW = 4 ' the frist data row
    ' ***
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Setting to 'false' speeds up the macro
    Dim txtShopOrdNum As String: txtShopOrdNum = ""                            'clear txtShopOrdNum, v13
    Sheets("Master").Activate
    If Me.txtSearch.Value = "" Then               'Condition if the textbox is blank
        MsgBox "Please enter a search value.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Search" 'vbOKOnly shows only the OK button, vbExclamation shows exclamation point icon
        txtSearch.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If cboSearchItem.Value = "" Then              ' Condition if combobox is blank
        MsgBox "Please select search criteria.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, ""
        cboSearchItem.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim aIndex: aIndex = Split(COL_INDEX, ",")
    Dim ColCnt As Long: ColCnt = UBound(aIndex) + 1
    With lstMaster                                'Need to clear the listbox first
        .Clear
        .ColumnCount = ColCnt
        .ColumnWidths = COL_WIDE
    End With
    Call Main                                     'Progress bar
    deg2 = txtSearch.Value
    Select Case cboSearchItem.Value
        Case "Shop Order"
            RN = 5  'E                          'column number
        Case "Suffix"
            RN = 4  'D
        Case "Proposal"
            RN = 14 'O
        Case "PO"
            RN = 23 'X
        Case "SO"
            RN = 33 'AH
        Case "Quote"
            RN = 34 'AI
        Case "Transfer Order"
            RN = 41 'AP
        Case "Customer Nickname"
            RN = 96 'CR
        Case "End User Nickname"
            RN = 121 'DQ
    End Select
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, RN).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim arrData: arrData = Range(Cells(START_ROW, 1), Cells(lastRow, "DQ"))
    Dim iR As Long, arrRes()
    For sat = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        deg1 = arrData(sat, RN)
        If UCase(deg1) Like "*" & UCase(deg2) & "*" Then 'case insensitive AND searches the entire string
            ReDim Preserve arrRes(ColCnt - 1, iR)
            For c = 0 To ColCnt - 1                   'column indices, total column
                arrRes(c, iR) = arrData(sat, aIndex(c))
            Next c
            iR = iR + 1
        End If
    Next
    lstMaster.Column = arrRes
    ' OR
    ' lstMaster.List = Application.Transpose(arrRes)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    lblTotalSearchResults = lstMaster.ListCount
    lblTotalOrders = Range("MASTER").Rows.Count
    'Debug.Print s, c, c + 1, sat, deg1, deg2, RN, lblTotalSearchResults, lblTotalOrders
End Sub


Hi! I changed the column indices from 0-125 to 0-124, per your suggestion. It worked, except I got a new error on the same line: lstMaster.List(s.c)=Cells(sat,c+1). It is a Run-time error '-2147352571 (80020005)': Could not set the List property. Type mismatch.
I am intreged by the code you recommended. I'm very new to VBA. I'll test this to see how it goes. I like your suggestion of loading only the 9 columns. Would you be willing to show me how that's done?

I test your code and got an error on this line.
ReDim Preserve arrRes(125, iR) 'RunTime Error 13: Type Mismatch

There is a typo. Try the updated code.

Wow! What a difference "()" makes. Thank you @taller. Thank you so much! Would you mind assisting me with revising the code for loading on the 9 columns?

I hope I have time to work on it today.

Oh gosh, I really appreciate it. It doesn't have to be today. Luckily, I can work with what I have. I'm trying to slowly replace inefficient code with more efficient and appreciate the help.

I've updated the code. Note: it's Untest code. Please backup your file before testing.

Friendly hint: Using a listboxe's .Column property would simplify lstMaster.List = Application.Transpose(arrRes) to lstMaster.Column = arrRes as it represents already a transposed .List :-) @taller

I tested your code and used lstMaster.Column = arrRes as @T.M. suggested. However, I get a runtime error 380. Count not set the Column property. Invalid property value. I also tried lstMaster.List=Application.Transpose(arrRes) and still get the error. UPDATE: I like to type in the code. So, I went back and copy/pasted exactly what you have and now the error is gone, but the listbox shows no results.

If the first snippet works well, then lstMaster.List=Application.Transpose(arrRes) should work with the 2nd snippet. Set debug breakpoint on lstMaster.Column = arrRes and run the code, then check the value of arrRes in local window.

The code works perfectly.
I did the breakpoint as you suggested and arrRes value is blank, but under 'Type' it says Variant (0 to 9, 0 to 46). Which I'm guessing 0 to 9 is the columns and 0 to 46 is the number of rows that match the search. Just learned about the local window this week. Thank you so very much for your help!

Question re: Const COL_INDEX = "3,4,5,14,23,33,34,41,96,121" ' Col index which is showed in ListBox
3, 4, 5...etc. are the column numbers, not the column indexes. Why do you reference them as indexes?

'Type' it says Variant (0 to 9, 0 to 46) means arrRes is populated as expected. COL_INDEX is used as index of arrData(sat, aIndex(c)). It should be Col. numbers. What does arrRes value is blank mean? A screenshot of Immediate Windows is helpful.

I feel a little dumb. How do I share the screenshot?

Edit your post to upload an image.

Pls try Const COL_WIDE = "40;48;108;50;72;50;35;45;100;100"

Sorry for not responding sooner @taller. The code you provided works perfectly. Now, I need help with updating the Initialize procedure with the more efficient code to populate the listbox.  I've tried but not having much luck. I will ask for help with this in a new post.
